# C#: Excel Worksheet to Pivot Table using Open XML?

Tags: excel, openxml, pivot-table

I've got a spreadsheet for which I'd like to insert a PivotTable using the OpenXML SDK. That is, the equivalent of highlighting a spreadhseet grid then Insert>>PivotTable in a new sheet.

I haven't been able to find any sample code for this scenario out there.

Anyone have any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find much information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278324.aspx).

You can also find much information in this article: http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/12/21/7937.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah I had seen that before but not helpful. I did post a question there though.

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar task.

Take a look at this [Power Tools for OpenXML](http://powertools.codeplex.com/).

It really helped me, although now I need to figure out how to initialize the pivot table with some structure.